# And they're good?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> A - I saw my kids yesterday.
>
> B - **And they're good?**
>
> A - Yeah, they're fine.

1. Would "good" be perfectly natural here?
2. Would "and they're good?" be more common than "and they're doing good?"

Comment: Is this a dialogue you wrote yourself?

Comment: The majority of my North American friends would respond to the question **How are you?** by saying: **We're good, thank you** when they mean that they're fine. Or, more often, when they are just being polite without wishing to discuss their health.

Comment: @RonaldSole - I, and the majority of my British friends, would respond to the question 'How are you?' by saying: 'We're well (or very well), thank you'. Saying 'I'm good' would be heard by many as a claim of moral righteousness or an Americanism.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No argument. I spent a couple of decades working in the UK, where my experience coincides with yours. It's an Atlantic cultural split;.

Comment: @RonaldSole - it would be deeply frowned upon for any Brit to claim to be 'good' in a moral sense, so the perceived meaning would be the American one.

Answer (score 1):

The word "good" is possible, but problematic. It can mean "virtuous".  I don't think that this is the intention here, and I doubt that there would be any real ambiguity. Nevertheless, there are simple ways to avoid this:

> And they're all right?

> And they/re okay?

> And they're well?

> And they're doing okay?

Forming questions by intonation, like this, is possible. But an alternative is to ask a real question:

> Are they doing okay?

or an open question

> How're they doing?